# haproxy setup issue

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to setup haproxy on EC2 instance but facing below error:

> 503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this
>   request.

Any help is highly appreciated. I tried many ways but all in vain.

My haproxy version is 1.5 and this is `haproxy.cfg` file :

```
frontend  main

bind *:80
default_backend   server

backend server

    balance     roundrobin
    server node1  xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check maxconn 32
    server node2  xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check maxconn 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the config file you shared is not complete. It should contain mode http in frontend and backend server if not mentioned in global settings. 
Also check if you can access the webserver, it is up and running. 
Allow the connection on webserver through firewall.
You can also share full config file so exact issue can be identified.

Hope this helps!